# Как запустить Java через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

Как запустить Java приложение, так чтобы потом можно было обращаться к методам класса и свойствам объекта Java приложение на JavaScript ?

Comment: Что?? Где запустить? Вы имеете в виду, в браузере у клиента запустить java-апплет? Или какое вообще где приложение?

Comment: Да, я имею ввиду в браузере. На JavaScript есть функция ActiveXObject("name") которая позваляет запустить сторонние приложения. Но у меня ничего не вышло. Можно ли что-нибудь по этому поводу подсказать..

Comment: В JavaScript нет ActiveXObject. Забудьте про ActiveX. Нет никакого ActiveX. Это работает только в Internet Explorer. В наше время он нужен только настоящим фанатам-извращенцам :) PS: ну, разумеется, эта технология нужна там, где она нужна, но не для JavaScript и ни в коем случае не для Web.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, речь идёт именно об [апплете](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82) (документация есть [здесь](http://java.sun.com/applets/)).

Вам поможет, например, [LiveConnect](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/).